# How to get and image to shrink with flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am new to programmin and that sort of stuff I am trying to make a website but the part im stuck on is trying to make a row of images that will shrink with the website when it shrinks. Instead the pictures get moved down when you shrink the browser. it works fine without the pictures but whenever i add the images it gets weird.

Here is the code

```css
.flexbox-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.flexbox-item {
  width: 200px;
  border: 3px solid #333;
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 100px;
  flex-grow: 0;
  flex-basis: auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-shrink: 1;
}

.flexbox-container img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 30rem;
  display: inline-block;
}

.emo-issa {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  border-radius:100px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h1>
    Da bois
  </h1>
  <br>
  <h2>Introducing da Bois!
  </h2>

  <h3>
    First up we have got!
  </h3>


  <div class="flexbox-container">
    <div class="flexbox-item flexbox-item-1">

      <div>
        <a href="issastat.html"> <img class="emo-issa" src="images/issa-small.jpg" alt="emo ass guy "></a>
      </div>


    </div>

    <div class="flexbox-item flexbox-item-2">

      <div>
        <a href="issastat.html"> <img class="emo-issa" src="images/issa-small.jpg" alt="emo ass guy "></a>
      </div>
    </div>


    <div class="flexbox-item flexbox-item-3">

      <div>
        <a href="issastat.html"> <img class="emo-issa" src="images/issa-small.jpg" alt="emo ass guy "></a>
      </div>

    </div>
```

Comment: I know it's not regarding the answer but you should correct your HTML because it's totally invalid. For example, you cannot have a `<div>` before the `<body>` and you have to close it with `</body>`. Use a [HTML validator](https://www.freeformatter.com/html-validator.html) and then [format your HTML](https://www.freeformatter.com/html-formatter.html)  and [format your CSS](https://www.freeformatter.com/css-beautifier.html) to make it readable.

Comment: Try be more clear and specific when describing a problem - ie "it gets weird" doesn't tell the community what your code is doing exactly, making it more difficult to help you solve the issue.

Comment: Sorry I will try to be more clear next time.

Answer (score 4):

You can add '*flex-wrap: nowrap;*' to make flex item stay in single line. and make image

```
width: 100%;
height: fit-content;
```

to make image auto adjust the size

Answer (score 0):

you can use flexbox when you want to make responsive web (shrink web)and you can use

> @media Query

```css
.container {
    margin: 50px auto;
    width: 800px;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: center;
}

.gambar {
    width: 25%;
}

.gambar img {
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="your-css.css">
    <title>Galery</title>
</head>
<body>

    <div class="container">
        <div class="image"><img src="Your-image.jpeg" alt=""></div>
        <div class="image"><img src="Your-image.jpg" alt=""></div>
        <div class="image"><img src="Your-image.png" alt=""></div>
        <div class="image"><img src="Your-image.jpg" alt=""></div>
        <div class="image"><img src="Your-image.jpg" alt=""></div>

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

Remove `flex-wrap`. Also, I removed so many codes from your code. no need to them:

```css
.flexbox-container {
  display: flex;
}

.flexbox-item {
  width: 20%;
  height: 80vh;
  border: 3px solid #333;
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 100px;
  flex-grow: 0;
  display: flex;
}

.flexbox-container img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div>
<h1>
    Da bois
</h1>
<br>
<h2>Introducing da Bois!
</h2>

<h3>
    First up we have got!
</h3>


<div class="flexbox-container">
    <div class="flexbox-item flexbox-item-1">

      <div>
        <a href="issastat.html"> <img class="emo-issa" src="https://s4.uupload.ir/files/5c29cf910a706_8m.jpg" alt="emo ass guy "></a>
      </div>


    </div>

    <div class="flexbox-item flexbox-item-2">

      <div>
        <a href="issastat.html"> <img class="emo-issa" src="https://s4.uupload.ir/files/5c29cf910a706_8m.jpg" alt="emo ass guy "></a>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="flexbox-item flexbox-item-3">

      <div>
        <a href="issastat.html"> <img class="emo-issa" src="https://s4.uupload.ir/files/5c29cf910a706_8m.jpg" alt="emo ass guy "></a>
      </div>

 </div>
```